# Redirect query (?page=) to different URL?

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect anything with `?page=` or `?page=""` back to the homepage.

I tried `RewriteRule ^/\?page=(.*)$ / [R=301,L]` but it doesn't work.

Example:

`http://example.com/?page=` or `http://example.com/?page=test` or
`http://example.com/?page="test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [R,L]
```

Did the trick.

The RewriteCond part catches any query (.) and then the RewriteRule redirects it to a 404 page.